# Why would an English QC litigate in Federal Court in Sydney, Australia?

Tags: barristers

Jonathan Sumption was a Queen's Counsel who practiced at the London bar, before his direct appointment to the UKSC. He does not appear to have practiced, or know much, Australian law. He does not appear to have lived in Australia, or held a tenancy at any Australian barrister chambers. Thus why was Sumption QC practicing in Sydney? Why couldn't an Australian SC do Sumption's job? What could Sumption QC offer that no Australian SC could?

John Halley — in  pictures below — is now a judge on the [Federal Court of Australia](https://www.fedcourt.gov.au/about/judges/current-judges-appointment/current-judges/halley-j).

[Lawyers for Seven Network Ltd., British QC Jonathan Sumption (C) and **John Halley (R)**, move a box containing documents in the Federal Court in Sydney September 12, 2005. Seven Network Ltd., Australia's No. 2-ranked broadcaster, took on the country's most powerful media, seeking up to A$1.1 billion ($847 million) in damages over the failure of its pay TV station, C7. REUTERS/Lindsay Moller/Pool TBW/JJ](https://www.alamy.com/lawyers-for-seven-network-ltd-british-qc-jonathan-sumption-c-and-john-halley-r-move-a-box-containing-documents-in-the-federal-court-in-sydney-september-12-2005-seven-network-ltd-australias-no-2-ranked-broadcaster-took-on-the-countrys-most-powerful-media-seeking-up-to-a11-billion-847-million-in-damages-over-the-failure-of-its-pay-tv-station-c7-reuterslindsay-mollerpool-tbwjj-image379658791.html)

[image]

[AUSTRALIA - SEPTEMBER 12: Barrister Jonathan Sumption QC, representing Seven Network, leaves the Federal Court in Sydney, Australia, Monday September 12, 2005 after the opening submissions. Billionaire Kerry Stokes's Seven Network Ltd. lawsuit against Rupert Murdoch's News Corp. and Kerry Packer's Publishing & Broadcasting Ltd. began court hearings today, embroiling Australia's media moguls in a A$1.1 billion ($850 million) battle. (Photo by Jack Atley/Bloomberg via Getty Images)](https://www.gettyimages.com/detail/news-photo/barrister-jonathan-sumption-qc-representing-seven-network-news-photo/94892386)

[image]

[lawyer for Seven Network Ltd., British QC Jonathan Sumption, appears in the Federal Court in Sydney September 12, 2005. Seven Network Ltd., Australia's No. 2-ranked broadcaster, took on the country's most powerful media, seeking up to A$1.1 billion ($847 million) in damages over the failure of its pay TV station, C7. REUTERS/Lindsay Moller/Pool](https://www.alamy.com/a-lawyer-for-seven-network-ltd-british-qc-jonathan-sumption-appears-in-the-federal-court-in-sydney-september-12-2005-seven-network-ltd-australias-no-2-ranked-broadcaster-took-on-the-countrys-most-powerful-media-seeking-up-to-a11-billion-847-million-in-damages-over-the-failure-of-its-pay-tv-station-c7-reuterslindsay-mollerpool-image379771205.html?imageid=E6D4CEC5-585D-4618-8268-A53D71F18B31&p=1335310&pn=1&searchId=e2d5daf8d5b12e66a8817b540460f818&searchtype=0)

[image]

Comment: What makes you think he doesn't know much about Australian law? Many foreign solicitors lawfully practice in different countries, especially within the Commonwealth, as long as they are properly qualified and meet the immigration / residency requirements.

Comment: @Rick How many Australian cases has Jonathan Sumption QC appeared in? Sumption was a barrister, not solicitor.

Comment: What do the pictures add to this question, beyond showing that Halley did indeed practice, which there seems no reason to doubt. Is there any reason not to edit them out?

Comment: @DavidSiegel These pictures prove that Sumption appeared in Sydney IN PERSON. Some people didn't believe that Sumption did. They thought I was mistaken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Money

Law at the upper echelons is largely borderless. Multinational companies need multinational lawyers.

Australian arbitrators hear cases in Belgium. UK QC’s argue cases in New Zealand. Indian law firms draft contracts between French and American companies. Canadian human rights lawyers take on cases in Chad (admittedly, that’s probably pro bono).

Comment: "UK QC’s argue cases in New Zealand." Citation please?  "Canadian human rights lawyers take on cases in Chad." Human rights pays money??? In Chad???